# How do I speed up Angular 6 builds?

Tags: angular

I have a fairly large Angular 6 project with around 100 top-level (full-page) components, and a bunch of smaller control components (for buttons, forms,  etc). With ahead-of-time compilation, page reloads are very quick (< 2 seconds). However, the initial  `ng serve --aot` takes 30+ seconds, and each subsequent recompilation cause by file change takes ~15 seconds, even for the most minor change.

Is there a way to make compilations, or at least the recompilations faster? It seems angular is recompiling the entire project when only a minor part changes.

Would modularizing the project so that the components are lazy-loaded make a difference in build time, or is that purely for page-load time (once it's compiled)?

Comment: Try HotModuleReplacement

Comment: How many external modules are you importing? What's your bundle size? Do you have an SSD?

Answer (score 2):

for development， just use `ng serve` is recommend. if you add `--aot` parameter, it need more time to translate the html templates and styles to javasctipt at build time, but this translation can be done on the fly at browser side with jit compile, so just remove the `--aot` parameter will save lots of build time.

if your project is very large, it is recommend to split it into several `NgModules` , and load them on demand with lazy load.  when you change any thing in your project, angular cli will just compile the `NgModule` which contains the changes, so split project will save build time too.

at now angular will do a full page reload when you change your code, if you want a partial reload, you can try [hmr](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-configure-hmr), but hmr maybe have capability issues with the libraries you use in your project.

Comment: The thing is, without AOT, it only saves a few seconds off the build/compilation, but it adds about 10 seconds to the page reload, so it's a net loss. I haven't done modularization of angular components yet, does it help with both compile and runtime, or just runtime? I'm not comfortable with a non-official method like hmr at this time (I'm too new to web dev to understand it).

Comment: yes, it helps both compile and runtime by modular your app .

Answer (score 1):

It generally depends on which builds you're talking about here. There are builds that you deploy to production. For those, I guess it's pretty much a standard to use `--prod` flag with `ng build` that does all the optimizations like Tree Shaking for dead-code elimination. That's how your bundle size is highly optimized and smaller as compared to normal bundle. Now you can't really do much about it as it needs to take all that time to perform the optimizations on your bundle.

If you're concerned about serving your App after small changes while developing,  consider implementing Hot Module Replacement. It can save you a lot of time building your App.

Also, since it's only applicable to the development environment and not production, I don't really think you have anything to lose.

Also, it's not non-official. It's quite a standard these days. Even StackBlitz uses it. Don't believe me? See for yourself:

[image]

I think you should give it a try. You'll thank me later.

Here's an [easy to understand article](https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/enabling-hot-module-replacement-angular-6/) on how to implement it an Angular App that can help you implement HMR in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `--source-map=false` like

```
ng serve --source-map=false
```

While resulting code may be not super readable in debugger, generaly this option speeds up first build time, rebuild time and browser reload time with dev tools open